# Apache ProxyPass root to NodeJS and /admin to PHP-FPM

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, httpd, node.js, mod-proxy

I have been trying to handle all requests via a NodeJS, except those going to the /admin directory via mod_proxy, but with no success.

This is the configuration I came up with, but it is not working.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/sites/domain.com/

    RewriteEngine on
    ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/sites/domain.com/

    ProxyRequests on
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*)$ http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassMatch ^/admin/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/home/sites/domain.com/php/public/$1 timeout=600
    ProxyTimeout 600

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/keys/domain.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/keys/domain.com.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Try moving the second `ProxyPassMatch` above the first.

Comment: @CraigWatson you should type that in a "Answer" because that's what happens. Most specific uri must go first when using proxypass, first is overriding second. Also `ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*)$ http://localhost:3000/`looks odd, are you sure you don't want to do `ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `ProxyPass` directives, the ordering matters, so you should move your second directive above the first.

Also, as ezra-s mentioned in their comment, you only need to add the `(.*)` if you intend on passing that to the destination, this should work:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/admin/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000/home/sites/domain.com/php/public/$1 timeout=600
ProxyPassMatch / http://localhost:3000/
```